# Crude and Standardized Death Rates and What They Imply?

Tags: statistics

I want someone to give a clear explanation on what a "**higher** standardized death rate, but **lower** crude death rate" and "**lower** standardized death rate, but **higher** crude death rate" imply about the population(s) at hand?
Our Statistics textbook isn't particularly informative.

Comment: After small issues aged 0, death rates tend to increase with age.  So consider what might happen with a population with an excess of young people compared with the standard distribution, or a population where  death dates were higher for each age.  How might these and other patterns interact?

Comment: Not exactly helpful, mind.

Comment: I get that a higher crude rate and lower standardized rate would imply that the population has many elderly compared to another one. But I want a little mathematical explanation.